# Azure website trial set to "Limited" status

Tags: azure

We signed up for the windows azure 90-day free trial and created 4 websites, 2 virtual servers and 2 SQL databases. They've been running for about a month now and have been doing great.

Tonight, I got a call from a user that none of them are up. So I went to the dashboard to find:

[image: azure websites trial limited status]

There's no tool-tip on the "Limited" status, and I can't find anywhere in the trial description as to why they would be limited. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same issue. NO documentation anywhere, but I found this. Hopefully this is the cause. I am in West US as well:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

Comment: An outage would definitely cause this. :) Here's hoping they fix it soon!

Answer (score 0):

Several people seem to be [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538361/why-does-my-azure-website-status-become-limited) this question right now. Might be an outage.